# Método para cargar un fragment en un tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy creando una app con un tab layout con tres pestañas. Mi idea es mostrar un fragment en una de las pestañas con tres botones que cargarian nuevas informaciones en el fragment de la pestaña. Mi pregunta es qual es la mejor forma para trabajar en este sentido.

Tengo un PagerController que carga los fragmentos por defecto:

```
public class PagerController extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int numoftabs;

public PagerController(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    this.numoftabs = behavior;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new TabPerfil();
        case 1:
            return new TabGrup();
        case 2:
            return new TabCalendari();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numoftabs;
}
}
```

I luego en el fragmento concreto tengo un boton que carga nuevos datos y me gustaria que los cargara en el mismo fragmento y no en una activity nueva como lo hace ahora.

```
public class TabPerfil extends Fragment {

public TabPerfil() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_perfil, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    Button btnPerfil = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPerfil);

    btnPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent perfil = new Intent(getContext(), PerfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(perfil);
        }
    });
}
```

Cual seria la mejor opción para actualizar TabPerfil() en un nuevo Fragment?

Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TabPerfil extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_perfil, container, false);
 
        Button Supermercados =  view.findViewById(R.id.btnPerfil);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
        super.onActivityCreated(state);

        Button btnPerfil = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPerfil);

        btnPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                FragmentTransaction fragment = getFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ();
                fragment.replace (R.id.fragment_container, new PerfilFragment());
                fragment.commit ();
            }
        });
    }
```

Bueno aunque he podido llegar hasta aquí, en mi caso el fragment se sobrepone al tab así que pruebe a ver si le sirve y me cuenta, estoy buscando solucionar esa parte.

Comment: Gracias @micronet-compiuters, por mi parte ya resolvi esta duda. En mi caso utilize el código que has dicho pero remplazando el view donde cargava la informacion del Tab.